# Ubuntu crashes on boot-up (Raspberry Pi 4)

Tags: boot, 20.04, raspberrypi

When I fire up my Pi, the LED lights look normal until the green LED starts [blinking regularly non-stop](https://streamable.com/1x81ov) approximately 40 seconds after I turn it on. I read [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1485558&sid=54f009231837376a62d3de84932caad1#p1485558) and none of the flash codes matches my Pi.

I don't have an SD card and boot my Pi using an external portable HDD. It's running Ubuntu 20.04 on a headless setup. Prior to this happening, I wasn't able to SSH into my Pi so I pulled the plug on it to restart it. After that, I haven't been able to get back onto the OS.

I plugged my Pi onto my monitor with a HDMI cable and I see the red boot-up screen (with the Pi logo). Then it turns black, loses signal, signal comes back (but screen is still black), and loses signal again. It keeps repeating indefinitely.

Comment: Could it be simply underpowered?

Comment: @Jos I don't think so as I've been using the official RPi power supply for many months. Although, I'm down to check it out. Do you know how I can check if it's getting enough power?

Comment: I think the Pi 4 itself signals when it's underpowered during bootup. If it doesn't, replace it by some other form of USB power. Also, on a different system, check the HDD file system for errors (`fsck`).

Comment: "Pulling the plug" on the Pi has been known to corrupt the boot medium.

Comment: @waltinator Is there a way to deal with a Pi that's not responding to anything in this case that isn't pulling the plug? I wasn't able to SSH into it and none of the stuff I have on Docker (e.g. Jellyfin, Nextcloud) are functioning during this time.

Comment: @Jos I did fsck and I don't think there was anything wrong. But I think waltinator might be right. This has happened to me before and it's usually right after I pull the plug. The boot portion of my HDD might be corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Apparently, I ran `fsck` on just the boot partition of my HDD but not the rest of it. The solution for me was to run `fsck` on the rest of the partition that isn't the boot partition.